# Access control allow origin with ReactJS sample web app

Tags: reactjs, cors

I am facing problem with the following CORS issue when I run my ReactJS sample web app in Chrome browser.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://XXXX.XXX/YYY/ZZZ/' from origin 'http://localhost:3003' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

I read the solution and installed CORS Chrome plugin. I added REST URL in CORS settings as shown in below screenshot. I cleared Chrome browser history and try running ReactJS web app, but still it is throwing the same error. Can someone guide how to exactly fix this? I also tried

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
```

in code, but not fixed this issue.

[image]

Comment: Are you using create react app?

Comment: No. it's just a simple basic reactjs web code which calls a rest service using axios. The same code works fine for other public rest URLs for ex: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users - No issues with this with the same code

Comment: In that case, you need to use **proxy** to workaround CORS issue.

If you are using webpack-dev-server [check that tutorial](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-proxy).

Or you can install and set up [http-proxy-middleware](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware)

Comment: can you please elaborate? how to setup proxy?

Comment: Yes, because jsonplaceholder etc... is CORS enabled... But https://XXXX.XXX/YYY/ZZZ/ is not...

Comment: If your "basic react front end code" as you put it was bootstrapped with create react app it would be simple... If not you're going to write a little server in Node

Comment: @Stella what server do you use?

Comment: Can you post your package.json here so we can take a look?

Comment: Can you please explain what is the issue here actually? I am not sure about server details. I need to ask another team for that.

Comment: Here is a thorough explanation of your issue: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Answer (score 0):

You can try a workaround with https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com

Have a look at my solution in here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52986448/5692089